# Android Image Button Behaving Strangely

Tags: android, user-interface, imagebutton

I'm building an app framework for Android tablets, and I am running into a strange issue with some ImageButtons. These buttons (Next & Prev) are used to help navigate through "content pages" as part of the framework, and are using custom background drawables.

The issue is that whenever I click on the Prev button, the Next button highlights while the the Prev button does not. At first I thought it was a simple linking or @+id/ issue, but the Prev button's action is performed, not the Next button's.

Here is some relevant code:

In onCreate() method:

```
nextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
prevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prevButton);
nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
prevButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(_cpp == null){
        finish();
    }else if (v == nextButton) {
        if (!_cpp.nextRes.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            // load next page
            _tempRes = _cpp.nextRes;
            //start transition out animations
            fadePageOut();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else if (v == prevButton) {
        if (!_cpp.prevRes.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            // load previous page
            _tempRes = _cpp.prevRes;
            //start transition out animations
            fadePageOut();
        }
    }
}
```

My drawable XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable= "@drawable/prev_arrowhigh" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/prev_arrowhigh" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/prev_arrow" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/prev_arrow" />
</selector>
```

I've been debugging and searching for answer for two days now, with no luck. The funny thing is it used to work just fine... but even reverting to a previous version of my project didn't seem to help at all.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any idea what could possibly be the cause of this?

Comment: are the "prev" and "next" buttons using the same drawable (with rotation)? that could be the problem

Comment: No, they use two separate drawables. prev_button.xml and next_button.xml. These are set in the layout XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! stupid, stupid me...

Next button was displaying as selected because in my code (part not posted) disables the button during my fadePageOut() method (see posted code). The state-drawable was simply using the wrong images for enabled/disabled states.

This:

```
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/prev_arrowhigh"/>
```

Should have been:

```
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/prev_arrow"/>
```

two days wasted because of a incorrect image...
*sigh*

Answer (score 0):

A solution you can try is to set the onClick attribute on your view. The solution might look like this:

onCreate method:

```
nextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
prevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prevButton);
```

new methods for the Activity:

```
public void nextButton(View v)
{
    if(_cpp == null || _cpp.nextRes.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    // load next page
    _tempRes = _cpp.nextRes;
    //start transition out animations
    fadePageOut();
}

public void prevButton(View v)
{
    if(_cpp == null)
    {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    if (!_cpp.prevRes.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        // load next page
        _tempRes = _cpp.nextRes;
        //start transition out animations
        fadePageOut();
    }
}
```

and add:
 **android:onClick="nextButton"**
 **android:onClick="prevButton"**

to your your buttons in the xml file

Comment: This is great as an alternative to using setOnClickListener(), but not as a solution to my problem (I did try it). My click events seems to be handled correctly by Android, it is just changing the images on the wrong button.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Worth a try to change the approach.. :) Did you try to remove the styles and drawable for the prev button to see if with the default style still behave weird?

Comment: I just tried using Buttons instead of ImageButton w/ background drawable and it works fine then. Do you think the issue could be something in my drawable XML file?

Comment: I just tried using my next_button.XML drawable (which works perfectly for the Next button) for both buttons and the issue persists. :/

Comment: well you can swap the position of the previous and next button (on the layout) to check if the issue is in the xml file

Comment: Tried that...and it doesn't help.

I'm at the point now where I'm ready to go sacrifice a virgin to the Android gods in exchange for a solution lol

Comment: Well the sacrifice must've worked! I found a solution. I will post as soon as the system allows me.